# Changing header table image with js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I'm doing a Dynamic Actions on load for changing the image from a table header that in css look like this:

```
.apexir_WORKSHEET_DATA th {
  background: url("../images/report_bg.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #AAAAAA;
}
```

i have uploaded a image and with javascript and jquery i'm doing this:

```
$('.apexir_WORKSHEET_DATA th').css({'background': '#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#header_image.gif'});
```

but with firebug i'm seeing that the image is failing to load, how can i solve this?

Comment: is to where i have upload the image. i called from #WORKSPACE_IMAGES#

Comment: then your location is not correct, try to access this location through your browser by typing url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to put `url()` around the image. Try this instead:

```
$('.apexir_WORKSHEET_DATA th').css({'background': 'url("#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#header_image.gif")'});
```

Just some other thoughts, though:

- Do you really want to change the whole `background` property, or just `background-image`?
- Should `#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#` be in the image name? Will this be replaced?

Comment: the `background` property allows you to set all the background properties at once. Individually, the background properties are `background-color`, `background-image`, `background-repeat`, `background-attachment` and `background-position`. If you only want to change the image (and not how that image is positioned and repeated) then you probably only need to change `background-image` and not all the background properties. You can [read more about it here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).